# How to implement a clock enable in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, counter, clock

So basically what I'm trying to do is to activate and deactivate a clock after a certain time. Here's a little example of what I'm looking for : `

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity example is
  generic (
    clk1       : in  std_logic; --- 100hz
    clk2 : in std_logic ;       --- 10hz

    );
end example;

architecture example_arch of example is

signal clk_count1, clk_count2 : integer range 0 to 1000:= 0;
signal clk_enable1 :  std_logic := '1';
signal clk_enable2 :  std_logic := '0';

begin

process (clk1)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk1) and clk_enable1 = '1' then
        if clk_count = 1000 then
             clk_enable1 <= '0'; 
             clk_enable2 <= '1'; 
             clk_count1  <= 0; 
        else
             clk_count1 <= clk_count1 + 1;
             [...] --- do what you want to do while you are using clk1
        end if;
   end if;
  end process;

process (clk2)
      begin
        if rising_edge(clk2) and clk_enable2 = '1' then
            if clk_count2 = 1000 then
                 clk_enable1 <= '1'; 
                 clk_enable2 <= '0'; 
                 clk_count2  <= 0; 
            else
                 clk_count2 <= clk_count2 + 1;
                 [...] --- do what you want to do while you are using clk2
            end if;
       end if;
      end process;

end example_arch;
```

`
So in this example we have two clock where clk1 has a greater frequency than clk2. When clk_enable1 is '1', we are working with the first process and when clk_enable2 is '1', we are working with the second one.

The problem with this code is that even if we know what clk_enable is at '1', it stills allow the two process to execute themselves after each clock events of the two clocks. What I'm trying to do is to deactivate a clock while I'm using the other one so that there is no clock events with the clock that I've deactivated so we never execute the process of this clock while we're executing the other process. In other words, when a clock can be at 1 or 0, the other is in high impedance (Z). I want something like this :

[flip-flop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKOEx.png)

Thank you for your help, hoping that I find a solution.

Comment: VHDL is a Hardware Description Language (the HDL part of VHDL), but based on your description it sounds like you do not take into account that the wires for hardware clocks will be connected to flip-flops all the time, thus result in update of flip-flop when at rising edge of the clock.  So, if you want to use VHDL to design a specific circuit, I suggest that you start by drawing the circuit, and then afterwards makes the VHDL code that implements the circuit.  If this is a question about VHDL simulation only, please state that, since it it removes a lot of constrains when doing the VHDL code.

Comment: Look at the picture that I've added, my question is how can we translate this into VHDL. Does my code is sufficient for what I'm looking for and I'm thinking too much ? @MortenZilmer

Comment: Look up "gated-clock". Make two gated clocks going to an OR gate. Then use that signal in a process. Even then there are still many pitfalls to do with preventing 'runt' pulses.

Comment: Note your `clk_enable1` and `clk_enable2` are both driven from two processes.

Comment: @ProgWriter10: Clock enable is never done like that in hardware, since you do not have undriven (Z) values on chip.  So you have to look at the way clock gating is done in your target hardware technology.